# Why does the order of the "or" boolean operator matter in C++?

Tags: c++

For this recursive function, it runs perfectly fine as below

```
void dfs(vector<vector<int>> &grid, int i, int j, int& sum) 
    {
        if(i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= grid.size() || j >= grid[i].size() || grid[i][j] == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        sum++;
        grid[i][j] = 0;
        
        dfs(grid, i+1, j, sum);
        dfs(grid, i-1, j, sum);
        dfs(grid, i, j+1, sum);
        dfs(grid, i, j-1, sum);
    }
```

However, once I change the base case to this, it gives me an out-of-bounds error. Can anyone explain why this occurs if just one true statement can make it true? Thank you so much and have a nice day!

```
if(i < 0 || j < 0 || j >= grid[i].size() || i >= grid.size() || grid[i][j] == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
```

I played around with the operators a bit. Since the boolean operator evaluates left to right and because it just takes one true statement to trigger the base case, i'm unsure why the latter produces out of bounds.

Comment: The second version accesses `grid[i]` before confirming that `i` is in fact in range, via `i >= grid.size()`. Logical operators `&&` and `||` *short-circuit* - meaning, they don't evaluate the second operand if the first is sufficient to produce the result. This allows one to write things like `if (p && p->Something())` and it won't end up trying to dereference a null pointer.

Comment: Use the debug mode of your standard library, it will tell you what is going wrong at runtime.

Comment: It's called "short-circuiting" and is mandatory for C++: `a || b || c || d` always (more or less) evaluates like this: evaluate `a`, return `true` immediately if it's `true`. Otherwise, proceed to evaluating `b`, etc. In your case it's important to check for array bounds before actually accessing the array.

Answer (score 6):

You may get a case where `i >= grid.size()`. Then, if you check `j > grid[i].size()` without first checking `i`, you are accessing an out of bound element and attempting to call `size` on it. This is undefined behavior, and anything may happen here.

The difference is that the compiler evaluates boolean expressions in the order they're written, and in the case of `||`, if it finds one expression that evaluates to `true`, it stops evaluating the rest (because there's no reason to).

For example, if `a || b || c || d` is what is being evaluated, if `a` evaluates to true, the compiler immediately exits the if statement without checking `b`, `c`, or `d`, because it doesn't matter what `b`, `c`, or `d` evaluate to, the final result of the expression is still `true` no matter what.

So, if `i >= grid.size()` is `true`, the compiler evaluates that to true and stops evaluating the rest of the expressions, so it doesn't check `j >= grid[i].size()`, which doesn't cause undefined behavior. In the other case, it evaluates `j >= grid[i].size()` before checking `i`, and that's where the undefined behavior occurs.

Answer (score 0):

@azhen7 explained it already well enough, but maybe it can also help to read it in other words:

### What we need to know

First we must know how the following code snippet is evaluated:

```
i < 0 || j < 0 || j >= grid[i].size() || i >= grid.size() || grid[i][j] == 0
```

1. Due to the operator precedence all comparisons in between the OR-operator symbols are evaluated. (Take a look at the priorities here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence )
2. Then the code is evaluated from left to right due to two reasons regarding the mechanisms of the OR-operator:

   1. The associativity of the OR-operator is left-to-right. (There is also an explanation about this in the link I provided.)
   2. The OR-operators have the same precedence level.

Furthermore it's good to know that, for performance optimization reasons, C++ realizes a so called "short-circuit evaluation" (you can read about it, e.g., here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation and here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical ).

For us that means that the whole expression will evaluate to `true` as soon as one of the terms (the operands of the OR-operation) returns `true`. It's not necessary to check the other terms then.

So our computer will evaluate the comparisons first, then check whether one of them is true by going from left to right in exactly that order:

- Is `i < 0` true? Yes: ignore the rest, jump into case handling. No: Check the rest.
- Is `j < 0` true? Yes: ignore the rest, jump into case handling. No: check the rest.
- Is `j >= grid[i].size()` true? Yes: ignore the rest, jump into case handling. No: check the rest.
- Is `grid[i][j] == 0` true? Yes: directly jump into case handling. No: Don't handle the case.

### The critical part

Comparing `i` and `j` with the `0` first does not cause any issues. Assume that those two expressions will evaluate to `false` (otherwise we would not reach the remaining terms due to the short-circuit evaluation). So what remaining values can `i` and `j` possibly have when we do this:

```
j >= grid[i].size()
```

?

We checked before that `i` and `j` are not smaller than zero. So the remaining possible values range from `0` to the maximum possible value of the type `int` (which can be a huge number).

Now we want to access element `i` in the first dimension of our `grid`. And here lurks the devil: We did not check whether there even exists an element with the index `i`. So if our grid has in the first dimension, for example, `5` elements and `i` is `9` we would land out of bounds when trying to access a (non-existing) element `9`. This is where the error arises.

Consequently, you need to make sure that `i` is not only a non-negative number, but also that our outer `std::vector<...>` has at least `i` number of elements, i.e., check whether `i < grid.size()`.

### Why did it work before?

Before you checked first whether `i >= grid.size()` (which is a negation / inversion of `i < grid.size()` ). When this evaluates to `false`, we then know that `i` is neither a negative number, nor a value larger than the number of elements in our outer vector (`grid.size()`). This makes `i` safe to use for accessing elements in the outer vector, which is why we can then safely check whether `j >= grid[i].size()`.

Hope that helps. Don't hesitate to ask further questions in the comments if you have any.